# object is being created twice angular

Tags: angularjs, grafana

I am using angular and grafana in my project.
I have a `service` -> `dashboardViewStateSrv`

My Service Code :

```
define([
  'angular',
  'lodash',
  'jquery',
],
function (angular, _, $) {
  'use strict';

  var module = angular.module('grafana.services');

  module.factory('dashboardViewStateSrv', function($location, $timeout) {

    function DashboardViewState($scope) {
      var self = this;
      self.state = {};
      self.panelScopes = [];
      self.$scope = $scope;
     // something
    }

    return {
      create: function($scope) {
        return new DashboardViewState($scope);
      }
    };

  });
});
```

In My side menu controller :

```
 $scope.dashboardViewState = dashboardViewStateSrv.create($scope);

    if ($scope.dashboardViewState) {
       if($scope.dashboardViewState.state.citreedepth){
          depth = +$scope.dashboardViewState.state.citreedepth;
       }
    }
```

In My Dashboard controller :

```
$scope.dashboardViewState = dashboardViewStateSrv.create($scope);
```

`DashboardViewState` object is being created twice (Dashboard Ctrl and Side Menu ctrl). 
I am creating `DashboardViewState` object twice, I want to avoid that. If I can avoid creating `DashboardViewState` object in Side Menu ctrl?

There should be only one view state. As per my understanding all the services are singleton in angular.

Please guide me what I can do?

Comment: Services are singleton but as you forcefully creating new object by doing `new DashboardViewState($scope)` is creating a new instance of `DashboardViewState` & assigning new `this` context to it.

Comment: If I am not wrong, do you want to call factory once and use it across the various controllers?

Comment: Anand Yes, correct.. Means I can include once and use it always..

Comment: @PankajParkar So the code what I have written is correct.

Comment: Edited my code a bit..

Answer (score 1):

Services are singletons, they are essentially a constructure function allowing you to use the `this` keyword inside them. They are instantiated once when first created then that instance is shared throughout your app.

Factories are, well, factories. Somewhere in Angular it will call `Object.create()` on the object your return from a factory. Meaning each call will return a new instance of it.

So in your use case your creating a new object twice. First by using a factory, then second by returning a new object from that factory.

This may help http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

So if you want a single instance of an object through your application you should use `.service()` not `.factory()`;

If you want to instantiate a new Object only once you could use a service. Have the object as a property and a get method. The service could check if the object is already created and if not make it.

something like this (example code, not tested):

```
  module.service('dashboardViewStateSrv', function($location, $timeout) {

    this.object;

    this.get = function (){
        if(this.object === undefined) {
            return this.object = Object.create({}); //Create your object
        } else {
            return this.object;
        }
    }
});
```

however i did notice some booboo's (Sorry always reminds me of Hook when i say that). First you do not need to alias the `this` keyword, were not working in an jQuery callback, even if we were you can bind your function etc.

Second and this is important. Your passing a `$scope` object into your service, this is very very bad. Not just for this reason but how can controllers share a single service object if it has a reference to a `$scope`? Your services should be a collection of single simple methods that have their input and output data. They work on that and continue. You can then chain them and pass them the specific data each method needs. They shouldn't be a monolithic object that has everything in hidden properties, think functional, a pipeline if you will.

Comment: I am using grafana in my project and grama have these concept in it.
Any other solution instead of using service in lace of factory..

Comment: I should use factory or service ??

Comment: You can use either. http://jsfiddle.net/dL6v98zo/ However both you need to keep a reference to the object you've created so you know if you've already created it. A service may be slightly more performant as its not being run through `Object.create` every time you inject it. However both feel 'wrong'. Look at the prototype of each logged Object. The first controller sets its data. Even though the second controller passes data to be set they both receive the already created object.